# Custom action after submit Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress

I am using Contact Form 7 on Wordpress and I need put the scripts after the Submit button is clicked - and I really have no idea how to do it right. Can you please tell me easy way to implement it?

The codes are - one iframe url and the other is javascript code.

Comment: You could add an event handler to `wpcf7submit`, which would allow you to do what you need / want to do after the submit button is clicked. See [Contact Form 7 - DOM Events](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

Contact Form 7 has a **wpcf7_mail_sent** hook for exactly this. Usage looks a little like:

```
// ...in functions.php
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', function ($cf7) {
    // Run code after the email has been sent
});
```

There is also **wpcf7_mail_failed**, which lets you hook into when the email fails.

**Or**

```
on_sent_ok: "ga( 'send', 'event', 'Contact Form', 'submit' );"
```

You should replace it with:

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    ga( 'send', 'event', 'Contact Form', 'submit' );
}, false );
```

The JavaScript code can be placed e.g. in the footer of your page.

Answer (score -2):

Go to 'Contact Form 7' plugin directory then open 'contact-form.php' file located in 'includes' folder. Find line with 'action' string and change value to your response.

```
  'action' => esc_url( $url ) // should be original line
  'action' => 'send.php' // i guess it what you need
```

Comment: You should NEVER modify plugins or themes directly, unless you are planning to maintain that plugin yourself and manually remove it from the update circuit. Otherwise, with the next plugin update you will lose all your changes.